# Grabbing elements of array with a function

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I'm trying to get each element of an array as the property values of some objects. Therefore I was using a function but it's not dynamic at all because I need to always specify the index of the array after calling the function.

This is my code:

```js
function grab(){ 
    var arr= [123456,987654]
 return arr
}

var arrayObjects= [
    {title: "miami", hash: grab()[0]},
    {title: "new york", hash: grab()[1]}
]

console.log(arrayObjects[0].hash)
```

What's another more efficient approach?

Comment: Why are you using `grab` as a function? Why don't you just declare the array where you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```js
function grab() {
    var arr = [123456, 987654];
    return arr;
}

var hashes = grab();
var arrayObjects = [{title: "miami"}, {title: "new york" }];

arrayObjects.forEach((item, index) => item.hash = hashes[index]);

console.log(arrayObjects[0].hash);
```

This is a simple snippet. An index validation could be helpful to avoid out of range exceptions when trying to access `hashes` array inside the `forEach` loop. But is just an example.

Comment: Suggestion: `function grab() { return [123456, 987654]; }`. Or ditch the function altogether.

Comment: @Cerbrus I just copied OP's code because it could be just an example of a bigger function or from another source, idk.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.Directly Pass the value with in a function

```js
function grab(n) {
return [123456, 987654][n];
}

var arrayObjects = [{ title: "miami" }, {  title: "new york"}]
arrayObjects.forEach((a,b)=> a['hash'] = grab(b));
console.log(arrayObjects[0].hash)
```

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, the function could have any kind of validation and return null in case of a error or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about indexes, you may wish to turn `arr` variable into an object with some sort of id specified, and call your hases using this id. For example:

```
function grab(){
  var hashes = {
      'miami': 123456,
      'ny': 987654
  };
  return hashes;
}
var arrayObjects= [{title: "miami", hash: grab().miami}, {title: "new york", hash: grab().ny}]
```

Comment: What's the point in using a function to declare an object if you're going to call that function that often. Then at least pass the key into the function and only return the value you need.

Comment: Don't ask me, it's asker's snippet :) I just changed it for the sake of an answer, without going too much into clean code, because he never ask for this.